# How to make own lifecycle hooks on VueJs?

Tags: vue.js

I want to make my own lifecycle hook on VueJs which need to be executed before the **beforeCreate** hook. On that custom hook, i want to execute some of my functionalities.

Comment: Usually, using already created hooks is enough to develop application. Maybe you should  rethink the logic of your programm

Comment: The framework is responsible for calling lifecycle hooks. If you need your own hooks, you need your own framework. This is XY problem, consider explaining it instead of addressing potentially wrong solution.

Comment: If you need to add something before `beforeCreate`, you should implement it into your `main.js`, maybe as a [Plugin](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html)